# How to get Mobile Country and Network code on an iPhone

Tags: iphone, country-codes, core-telephony

Is there any way of getting the mnc and mcc numbers on an iPhone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the CoreTelephony framework

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
```

to get MNC,

```
NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
```

to get MCC,

```
NSString *mcc = [carrier mobileCountryCode];
```

Comment: Thanks. The question was asked in 3.2 time so this wasn't a solution for my first problem. But that was over a year ago so if I don't have to be compatible with old devices, this is the best solution.

Comment: In order to retrieve the CTCarrie your need the Network info first: `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init]; CTCarrier *carrier = [networkInfo subscriberCellularProvider];`. The code in the answer will return nil for both.

Comment: why is this marked as the correct answer? My country code for my phone number is +1, I am not getting that using this solution...

Comment: @zumzum The "country code" you're looking for and the standardized MCC is not the same thing...

Comment: deprecated in iOS 16.0. with no replacement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods of the CTCarrier class to retrieve Country and network code. However this is only for the home provider (=SIM Card) and not the provider the phone is currently booked in,

Comment: Any way of getting the one the phone is currently booked in?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't an official method to do this at the moment.